# what is the use of --symlink-install in ROS2 colcon build?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having difficultly understanding the difference between a normal `colcon build` and `colcon build --symlink-install`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371822/what-is-the-use-of---symlink-install-in-ros2-colcon-build?/) by [Shiva_uchiha](https://answers.ros.org/users/37455/shiva_uchiha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2021-02-15

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ThomasL624](https://answers.ros.org/users/50229/thomasl624/) on 2022-10-20**:
Hi base on this question, I would like to ask could I remove the `src` `log` `build` directories after `colcon build --symlink-install`?

The reason for doing that is I want to mount a volume (which is the ROS2 workspace) from Host into a docker container.

So, I have to:

1. `COPY` the workspace (include packages), `WORKDIR` to that path in Dockerfile and `mkdir src`
2. Run `rosdep update && rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO`
3. Run `RUN source /opt/ros/"$ROS_DISTRO"/setup.bash && colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

This will generate the `install` `build` `log` `src` directories inside the container, which **will not** be used, as the host volume will mount and replace  it.

Should I delete it? or will it breaks the packages? If so, what is the best approach to mount a workspace from Host which already built in Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

with symlink-install if you change code in your source code, it will take effect, you don't have to compile it again (ony with python, not c++)

---

Originally posted by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) with karma: 187 on 2021-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sansevieria22](https://answers.ros.org/users/75265/sansevieria22/) on 2021-06-07**:
very nice! Thank you very much!

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2021-06-11**:
also for urdf I believe. PS @sansevieria22 please accept the answer as the correct answer, to remove it from the 'unanswered' list.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2021-07-15**:
but do you need to use `. install/setup.bash` anyway?

**Comment by [Mahmoud Kamel](https://answers.ros.org/users/30538/mahmoud-kamel/) on 2021-07-27**:
Yes, You still need to source setup.bash so that the packages / nodes in this local workspace would be available to use.
You can add it to your .bashrc file:
source ~/PATH_TO_WS/install/setup.bash

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> with symlink-install if you change
> code in your source code, it will take
> effect, you don't have to compile it
> again (ony with python, not c++)

There is also an additional very good advantage for c++. When you use IDE such as VScode the navigation funcionality works better. For example, if you navigate from the integrated terminal to some error in a header file, it brings you to the source code file (instead of the install folder file)

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2021-08-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4